# Socket.io on elastic beanstalk error

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I get an error

```
http://lowcost-env.b8cgexs3tc.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LliRJNu 404 (Not Found)
```

when I have deployed my app and try to run it. Socket.io works great locally on localhost.

My server-setup:

```
var server = require('http').Server(express);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);


server.listen(8080);
```

Client:

```
   io.connect('LowCost-env.b8cgexs3tc.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com')
```

The errorlog from Amazon show:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1259:14)
at listen (net.js:1295:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1391:5)
at EventEmitter.listen (/var/app/current/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/server/index.js:8:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
Tue, 09 May 2017 11:30:38 GMT express-session deprecated undefined resave 
option; provide resave option at server/app.js:27:9
Tue, 09 May 2017 11:30:38 GMT express-session deprecated undefined 
saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option at server/app.js:27:9
```

In Amazon I have disabled proxy so I'm not using nginx. Whats the problem here?

Comment: have you tried actually connecting to port 8080 from the client side? Like `io.connect('LowCost-env.b8cgexs3tc.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com:8080')`

Comment: Yes, I tried that without any luck.. Updated my question